# SVM Kernel for MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Facts:

- Support Vector Machines is a well known Machine Learning algorithm.
- MNIST is a popular hand written digit recognition contest.
- SVMs are almost as good as *hand tuned* neural networks.
- In using SVMS, the choice of Kernel function is crucial.

Question:

- In State of the art results on MNIST using SVMs, what kernels do people use?
- Assume that the inputs are 16x16 gray-scale images.
- I want to know what kernel to apply $K(x,z)$, where x/z are 16x16 images and $K$ is the kernel function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ under the SVM section. You will see that SVMs of gaussian and polynomial kernel get competitive results of <1.5% error.

If you want to go beyond that then you will need to create so called virtual examples (e.g. rotating, shifting, distorting the digits) and add additional normalization.

Comment: Ah, that's, what the "virtual" in "virtual SVM" means. Upvoted and accepted!

Comment: Fwiw, the number of coefficients needed to describe the SVM decision   boundaries for MNIST, e.g. save them in a file, goes from (10, 784) linear to (14374, 784) scikit-learn `SVC( kernel="rbf"`. (Sizes for neural nets, anyone ?)